# jquery post works only after alert

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, submit

I have function that submitted two forms at once. And last (the second) post method does not take effect without alert().

Could you please show me my mistake.

```
  function formFunction() {
        ...
        $.post($("#form1").attr("action"), $("#form1").serialize() );
        $.post($("#form2").attr("action"), $("#form2").serialize() );

        //alert('done');
}
```

UPD

this is how function is calling

```
<form id="form0" name="form0" onsubmit="formFunction()">
    <input id="mainFormValue" type="text">
```

Comment: How do you know that .. You do not have any call back function to capture the request ??

Comment: Ajax is asynchronous, so it works in the "background" so to speak, and something tells me you did'nt prevent the form from redirecting the page, so the page redirects, but when using the alert the redirect is halted long enough for the form to be sent with ajax. Or something similar to this.

Comment: Show how formFunction()  is being called.

Comment: This is not enough code to tell what is wrong.

Comment: what more code is needed to be clear?

Comment: @Sushanth-- yes, there is no callbacks but there is a response of API to which I sending this requests. Is it not enough and I had to set some callbacks?

Comment: I'd suggest putting an example up on jsfiddle

Comment: The Page is being refreshed people! No need more a jsFiddle or knowing anything about the callbacks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why it is failing is you are not cancelling the original form submission. That means the page is posting back to the server when you click the button. What you need to do is prevent that origial form submission from completing.

If you are adding the event handler with jQuery, you can use preventDefault() to cancel the form submission.

```
function formFunction(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     $.post($("#form1").attr("action"), $("#form1").serialize() );
     $.post($("#form2").attr("action"), $("#form2").serialize() );
}
```

Change the form submission to unobtrusive JavaScript to get the correct event object set by jQuery.

```
$("#form0").submit(formFunction);
```

The other solutions is add a `return false` to the submisison. Just ignore the preventDefault line I suggested above. [bad idea, but will work]

```
<form id="form0" name="form0" onsubmit="formFunction(); return false">
```

Comment: I've posted the UPD with function calling info. Does it fit you solution?

Comment: Oh, great! Unfortunely I do not understand what this does, but it works. Thank you very much!

Comment: The form is being submitted so it is refreshing the page not giving time for the code to run. The alert causes the page to pause which allows the Ajax request to be made. Hence why that version worked. If it solved your problem, please mark it as the answer.

Comment: @paka I edited the question so it hopefully makes more sense.

Comment: IE does not like return false solving. may be this will help «$("#form0").submit(formFunction);»...I'll try it later. This should be wrapped in $(document).ready ?